# Select SUM users by amount they spent

Tags: mysql, sum

SO I have table `orders` with the following structure:

```
id | user_id | order_amount | time_started | status
```

and I'm trying to get users who spent the most since given timestamp including `users` table to access their info.

`SELECT SUM(DISTINCT 'orders.order_amount') as 'amount_total' FROM 'orders' LEFT JOIN 'users' ON 'orders.user_id' = 'users.id' WHERE 'orders.time_started' >= "1484396552" AND 'orders.status' = 1 ORDER BY 'amount_total' GROUP BY 'orders.user_id' DESC`

but this query is invalid. The result I expect is:

`id | user_id | amount_total | user_data_from_users | user_data_from_users...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of lots of syntax errors such as

- single quotes instead of backticks `` ` ``
- order by before group by
- DESC added to group by

Try this:

```
SELECT `orders`.`user_id`,SUM(`orders`.`order_amount`) AS `amount_total`, `users`.*
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `users`
ON `orders`.`user_id`          = `users`.`id`
WHERE `orders`.`time_started` >= 1484396552
AND `orders`.`status`          = 1
GROUP BY `orders`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `amount_total` DESC;
```

Comment: thats seems working but It takes only one user, not all

Comment: takes one user? how do you mean?

Comment: This query is not complete correct and will fail on servers with sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY because GROUP BY is misused..... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @Raymond It works in MySQL out of the box. If it doesn't, you can easily add rest of columns to the group by clause.

Comment: @GurV not on the newest Mysql versions where sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled... but true you can easily add the rest off the columns

Comment: I have the latest version installed in my laptop and the sql works fine on it